# cannot import name 'InvalidArgument' from 'discord'

Tags: python, discord

I have a discord bot and I have made a ticket system, but what I am trying to do is making discord buttons for my command. When I ran the code, the below error code came up.

Code:

```py
from discord import PartialEmoji, Emoji, InvalidArgument
```

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidArgument' from 'discord'
```

Answer (score 1):

The InvalidArgument exception has been removed in version 2.0, you should raise a TypeError or ValueError instead

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=invalidargument#removal-of-invalidargument-exception